# php file upload for pdf and images

Tags: php, html, pdf, file-upload

I have the following code which is working fine for images but not for PDF. I'm suspecting the issue is with **getimagesize** when pdf is uploaded however I read that it is required for security reasons to block hackers fake images. how can I get it working for PDF as well.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "pdf" ) {
echo "Sorry, only PDF, JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
$uploadOk = 0;

if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
}
} 
?>
```

Comment: A PDF is not an image, and you need to treat it completely differently from one.

Answer (score 0):

Supported filetypes for reading image size using the GD library include:

> IMG_BMP | IMG_GIF | IMG_JPG | IMG_PNG | IMG_WBMP | IMG_XPM | IMG_WEBP

(https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagetypes.php)

Because PDF isn't listed, you'll need to use something that supports PDF to check file validity. PHP doesn't seem to have built-in functions to accomplish this (only functions for *creation* of PDFs).

Take a look at https://superuser.com/questions/580887/check-if-pdf-files-are-corrupted-using-command-line-on-linux for a couple options of such commmand-line utilities. You'll need to choose a utility that suits what you want to validate about the PDF file, your operating system, and any other requirements you may have. That thread suggests both `pdfinfo` and `qpdf`.

Use a system() call to run your chosen utility,

```
$result = system('pdfinfo '.$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $retval);
```

replacing `pdfinfo` with the name of your chosen utility that you've installed. Depending on the utility and the information returned, you'll have to adjust your script accordingly.